# The use of feature scaling in scikit learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression

I'm studing machine learning from here and the course uses 'scikit learn' from regression - https://www.udemy.com/machinelearning/

I can see that for some training regression algorithms, the author uses feature scaling and for some he doesn't because some 'scikit learn' regression algorithms take care of feature scaling by themselves.

How to know in which training algorithm we need to do feature scaling and where we don't need to ?

Comment: why down vote ? thats a logical question ?

Comment: Here's a full answer I wrote on just the question of scaling in general, which you might find useful: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/189652/is-it-a-good-practice-to-always-scale-normalize-data-for-machine-learning/189655#189655

Comment: It may have been downvoted because if your question is really specific to scikit learn implementations, it sounds like the proper answer is 'read the scikit learn documentation.' SO can be a little brutal, yes, but I think that would be the correct answer myself. ALSO, if you're doing ML, it should really go on the stats/datascience branches of the site, not here

Answer (score 3):

No machine learning technique *needs* feature scaling, for some algoirthms scaled inputs make the optimizing easier on the computer which results in faster training time.

Typically, algorithms that leverage distance or assume normality benefit from feature scaling. https://medium.com/greyatom/why-how-and-when-to-scale-your-features-4b30ab09db5e

Comment: So for my safety and stability in Scikit Learn, I should always apply feature scaling, no matter whether the algorithm I'm using has system of internally feature scaling or not. Right ?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the algorithm you are using and your dataset.

- Support Vector Machines (SVM), these models converge faster if you scale your features . The main advantage of scaling is to avoid attributes in greater numeric ranges dominating those in smaller numeric ranges
- In K-means clustering, you find out the Euclidean distance for clustering different data points together. Thus it seems to be a good reason to scale your features so that the centroid doesn't get much affected by the large or abnormal values.
- In case of regression, scaling your features will not be of much help since the relation of coefficients between original dataset and the relation of coefficients between scaled dataset will be the same.
- In case of Decision Trees, they don't usually require feature scaling.
- In case of models which have learning rates involved and are using gradient descent, the input scale does effect the gradients. So feature scaling would be considered in this case.

Comment: So for my safety and stability in Scikit Learn, I should always apply feature scaling, no matter whether the algorithm I'm using has system of internally feature scaling or not. Right ?

Comment: This is the most concise and helpful explanation of this topic I have found!

Answer (score 1):

A very simple answer. Some algorithm does the feature scaling even if you don't and some do not. So, if the algorithm does not, you need to manually scale the features.

You can google which algorithm does the feature scaling, but its good to be safe by manually scaling the feature. Always make sure, the features are scaled, otherwise, the algorithm would give output offset to ideal.

Comment: So for my safety and stability in Scikit Learn, I should always apply feature scaling, no matter whether the algorithm I'm using has system of internally feature scaling or not. Right ?

Comment: @Gissipi_453: It actually depends on your application.

When your data is dependent on the unit or scale, then it is a good practice to scale the data even if your algorithm does it.
Scaling has the benefit of computation time as well.
For a slower algorithm like SVM, it is best to scale the data, so that it converges faster.

Comment: @Gissipi_453: But when the units are essential to you, then you should not scale the data. And when you scale the data, the coeffients change, because your data has been scaled. So if the coeffients are important for you, avoid scaling the data.